# Android - Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps

Tags: android, apk, bundle, sign

In Android Studio, what is the "export encrypted key for enrolling published apps" function when generating signed APK/bundle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want Android Studio to also save the signature key as an encrypted file, then select the Export encrypted key check box. In order to be able to upload the bundle, you must also upload this encrypted file to the Google Play console and register the application with Google Play.

Comment: so if I understand correctly - to upload app bundle I need to check this box right?

Comment: "With App Signing, Google manages your app signing keys and uses it to sign your APKs for distribution. Enrolling your app in App Signing is optional. You might have decided to handle the signing and storage of your keys instead of uploading them to Google Play."

https://proandroiddev.com/opting-in-existing-apps-to-google-play-app-signing-19239853b57f